# почему hibernate создает таблицу но не записывает туда данные

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

класс контроллер

```
@Autowired
service s;

@RequestMapping(value ="/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView mod(HttpServletRequest req){
    ModelAndView md = new ModelAndView();

    String name =req.getParameter("log");
    String last = req.getParameter("pass");

    m.setName(name);
    m.setLast(last);

    s.addModel(m);
    md.setViewName("login");
    return md;
}
```

===============
класс сервис

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class service {

    @Autowired
    public SessionFactory ser;

    @Autowired
    model mod;

    @Transactional
    public void addModel(model m){
        ser.getCurrentSession().save(m);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public model getM(Long id){
        mod =(model)ser.getCurrentSession().get(model.class,id);
        return mod;
    }
}
```

- Элемент списка

Comment: может потому что вы данные не передаете? Где остальной код?(PS sesionFactory нашли?)

Comment: А у вас класс model с аннотациями? Добавьте его в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что у вас к методу addModel указана аннотация readOnly